# Debian 8: Server makes routers dhcp crash

Tags: debian, ip, crash, dhcp

I've got an old pc with debian 8 running as home server. A small problem is that whenever the server uses a lot of network traffic, let's say while downloading torrents, it seems to crash the dhcp of my router.

When this happens no device on the network has internet. In order to regain it I must first shutdown the server, then restart the router and then restart the server.

I've been searching the internet for ages but I can't seem to find what might cause it. I hope someone here does know.

Extra information
Running services

```
Apache2
Plex media server
Deluge incl. web interface
Sickrage
Samba
Webmin
```

DHCP server
192.168.1.1
255.255.255.0
802.1d Spanning Tree disabled
Lease time is one week
Scope 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.200

The servers has a static ip: 192.168.1.201

Please let me know if there is any information missing.

Comment: Everything here makes me suspect the router has some kind of bug. Make sure it has the latest firmware.  What happens if you disable DHCP server on the router?

Comment: A DHCP daemon dying wouldn't take down the internet for devices that are already connected. The settings the DHCP server gave those devices will be valid until the lease expires. I would say the router itself is dying.